# Deciphering a function overload not found error message

Tags: c++, linux, icc

I have the following code :-

```
class A : public B {
  public:
    _container (B* b) { 
      container_ = b;
    }
  private:
    B* container_;
};

void foo(const A& a, const B& b) {
  A new_a (a);
  new_a._container(&b);
}
```

If I try to compile this using icpc12, I get :-

```
error: no instance of overloaded function "A::_container" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (const B *)
            object type is: A
      new_a._container (&b);
```

Now, I understand that the first line of the error means there is some sort of type mismatch between the function being called and the function definitions available and I'm trying to narrow down the problem using the other two lines of the error message.

What do the second and third lines mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function takes a non-const pointer as an argument, and you're passing a const pointer.

Comment: well that fixed the bug but I still don't understand what the two lines are. There's hardly any hint of a const-ness mismatch.

Comment: The second line tells you that you've given it an argument of `const B*`. The third line tells you the method belonged to class A.  The first line told you there was no method of that name that took `const B*` - you just have to look at what the signature of A::_container is to see that there's no `const B*`, only `B*`.